# Spring Data Neo4j - '__type__' property not found for NodeImpl#0

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to play with neo4j with the help of spring data in my java application. Currently i'm facing a strange problem. Following is the scenario.

```
I have:
1. Two UserNode, say A and B, where "UserNode" is java @NodeEntity class. 
2. A @RelationshipEntity "RequestedTo" which is again a java class. 
3. A relationship "A RequestedTo B" which is directed towards B.
```

Now when i try to fetch all the UserNode which have a RequestedTo relationship directed towards B i get following exception

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: '__type__' property not found for NodeImpl#0.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.newPropertyNotFoundException(Primitive.java:184)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.getProperty(Primitive.java:179)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getProperty(NodeImpl.java:52)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(AbstractIndexingTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:106)
```

Here i do following query to neo4j using GraphRepository interface provided in Spring.

```
START user=node:searchByMemberID(memberID={0}) , member=node(*), root = node(0) MATCH user<-[r:RequestedTo]-member WHERE member <> root RETURN member
```

Also, when i fire this query in neoclipse i can see that there is no "*type*" property on UserNode in result. But when i try this query in neo4j browser console i can see the "*type*" property coming in the result set.

Comment: Did you insert your nodes with the core API or via Spring Data Neo4j? Only SDN creates this property to be able to map nodes to a POJO entity.

Comment: @tstorms is right; if you used the core API you should create this property by hand

Comment: @tstorms I used spring neo4j annotations "NodeEntity" and "RelationshipEntity" to annotate UserNode and RelatedTo class resp. Can you tell me what do you exactly mean by "core Api"?

Comment: Core API = Neo4j java API. Did you create your nodes with `GraphDatabaseService.createNode()`? Then no `__type__` property will be available as it's specific to SDN. If you persist nodes and relationships with a SDN repository or Neo4jTemplate, you should be fine.

Comment: @tstorms ohk... Yes,i am using Neo4jTemplate/GraphRepository and  not Core API. Basically i can see the _type_ property in neo4j browser console but not in neoclipse and somehow my code also throws exception.

Comment: @Prabhat Can you show some of your insertion code?

Comment: @tstorms that was the actual problem for me... used the batchinserter to input nodes. see also here: http://code.paananen.fi/2012/04/05/neo4j-batchinserter-and-spring-data-for-neo4j/

Answer (score 1):

I just played a little bit with Neo4j but try this instead:

```
START user=node:searchByMemberID(memberID={0}) , member=node(*)
MATCH user<-[r:RequestedTo]-member 
WHERE id(member) <> 0 
RETURN member
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify `member` in `start`, cypher takes care of that itself. After all local queries from a single or few starting points is what graph databases is about:

```
START user=node:searchByMemberID(memberID={0})
MATCH user<-[r:RequestedTo]-member 
RETURN member
```

Comment: Wow!!! now my query looks quite optimized... thank you :).. but would like you to look into the '__type__' property not found for NodeImpl#0 exception that i have originally mentioned...cheers

Comment: The node(0) has no __type__ property in this graph model, so you need to work around that.

Comment: @PeterNeubauer the problem is not with node(0), its with a node that was created by my code and is of type "UserNode".

Comment: @PeterNeubauer sorry to say, but even I have the same situation (type property not found) right now.. any guess how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as the OP:

```
'__type__' property not found for NodeImpl#0
```

and solved it by checking the existence of the `__type__` property using the `has` keyword.

More explicitly, this request raises the error:

```
@Query(value = "start n=node(*) where not (n)-[:hasParent]->() return n")
Set<MyNodeType> findRootNodes();
```

but this request works:

```
@Query(value = "start n=node(*) where has(n.__type__) and not (n)-[:hasParent]->() return n")
Set<MyNodeType> findRootNodes();
```

Hope this will help someone.